# Mutate Vuex array passed in the payload

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, state, vuex

What's the technical difference between next two approaches? Example is trivial but when I have huge nested objects, I need to pass lots of IDs in order to find desired object inside the mutation.

In second example I pass an array and just mutate it. Again, technically in both examples we invoke the same push method. Am I right? Should be the same.

```js
const state = () => ({
  cards: []
});

mutations: {
  addCard(state, card) {
    state.cards.push(card)
  }
}

// Component...

this.$store.commit('addCard', {...card});
```

and

```js
const state = () => ({
  cards: []
});

mutations: {
  addCard(state, data) {
    data.cards.push(data.card)
  }
}

// Component...

this.$store.commit('addCard', { cards: this.$store.cards, card: {...card} });
```

Comment: The second block is invalid.  A mutation definition shouldn't have 3 arguments.  Maybe you're missing some destructuring braces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What's the technical difference... ?

I know you're not asking what the literal difference is between the two, but I'll just make that clear first.

- In the first snippet, you're passing a new item and adding it to an array state that you access through the mutation's `state` argument.
- In the second snippet, you pass both the array state and the item, and access the array through the payload instead.

> Again, technically in both examples we invoke same push method. Am I right?

Yes, these two accomplish the exact same result.  The array state, whether accessed through the mutation argument or through the payload are the exact same object (i.e. `===`).

The pattern in the second snippet can be very useful when mutating deeply nested state, like you found. The drawback is that it might not be quite clear what's being mutated, to someone who tries to learn your code later.

Comment: Thanks! Second answer is what I was looking for. Good point on drawback but I find it really useful for deeply nested state.

Comment: You're welcome.  Yeah it's useful.  And for a small personal project, it should be ok.  For a giant team collaboration, this could be a problem to a team member studying the store code.  They will stumble on this mutation and have no idea what it really does.  But, some good documentation could potentially nullify that concern if it's useful enough.